# Adding smooth scrolling to function onclick getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this function part to show hidden div, it is working properly, but it appears suddenly, not nice, I want it to scroll down gently, what can I add to the code?

```js
function show() {
document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show();">Show</button>
</div>
<div id="show" style="background-color:#ccc;display:none;">
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m It is an option, but I always look for simple solutions, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this... using your existing code (and vanilla js) I would use a combination of `max-height` and `transition` to get the text to "scroll down":

```js
function show() {
document.getElementById("show").style.maxHeight = '50px';
}
```

```html
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show();">Show</button>
</div>
<div id="show" style="background-color:#ccc;max-height:0;transition:all 0.5s;overflow:hidden">
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the simplicity I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, you can use .slideDown("slow");

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#thebtn").click(function(){
    $("#show").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="thebtn">Show</button>
</div>
<div id="show" style="background-color:#ccc;display:none;">
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery. I use this:

```
$("#show").fadeIn(1000);
$("#show").fadeOut(1000);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#thebtn").click(function(){
     $("#show").fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="thebtn">Show</button>
</div>
<div id="show" style="background-color:#ccc;display:none;">
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```